# Why are deques used as the underlying container for stacks by default, when vectors would do the trick?

Tags: c++, stack, containers, std

As I understand, any container that supports push_back(), pop_back() and back() can be used as the underlying container for stacks, but by default, deques are used. I understand the pros of deques over vectors generally (possibility to add elements at the beginning as well as at the end), but in the case of stacks, I don't see any reason to prefer deques.

Comment: to phrase it provocative: why do you care if a stack has elements in contiguous memory when anyhow you can only access one of it at any time?

Comment: So vectors has the (in the case of stacks) irrelevant advantage of contigous memory, while deques has the (in the case of stacks) irrelevant advantage of supporting push_front(). And contigous memory just seemed MORE irrelevant (more expensive?) than supporting push_front()? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: deques are very good at pushing and popping at the end. vectors arent bad at this but not so much.

Comment: Really? Why are deques better at pushing and popping at the end?

Comment: its detailed in the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't see any reason to prefer deques.

A reason to prefer deque that applies to the stack use case is that individual push back has worst case constant complexity compared to vector whose individual push back is linear in worst case (it has amortised constant complexity over multiple push backs). This was particularly significant prior to C++11 when reallocating vector had to copy the elements which could be very expensive. Consider case where the elements themselves are long strings.

Another reason to prefer deques is that they release memory as they shrink. Vectors don't. Hence, if you have a stack that temporarily grows large, then shrinks and remains small for the rest of the execution, then an underlying vector would be wasting a lot of memory.

Historically, when STL was designed and thus when the default was chosen, there used to also be issues with very large vectors because the size of the address space didn't exceed (significantly, or at all) the amount of memory (this was before 64 bit processing was common). The consequence of the limited address space was that memory fragmentation would make it expensive or impossible to allocate large contiguous blocks of memory that a large vector would require. Furthermore, the way that vector grows by deallocating old buffers is a behaviour that causes such fragmentation.